# Breaking A* admissibility caused exponential speed-up?

Tags: a-star, heuristics

I've been working on a generalized version of the sliding tile puzzle where the tiles do not have numbers. Instead, each location either has a tile or a hole and is represented with a boolean as true or false (tile or hole).

The point of the search is to take an initial state with n tiles and a goal state with n target locations and use A* to find the solution of how to move the tiles so that every target location is populated. Here is an example below for a 4x3 grid:

```
Initial State:
T F T F
F F T F
F F T T

Goal State
T T T T
T F F F
F F F F
```

I had been working on different heuristics to do this and the most successful had a logic that went something like this:

```
int heuristicVal = 0

for every tile (i)...
int closest = infinity
for every goal location (j)...
if (manhattan distance of ij < closest) closest = manhattan distance of ij
end for
heuristicVal += closest
end for

return heuristicVal
```

Unfortunately, this was still too slow in situations where two or more tiles were being guided by the heuristic to the same target location. I tried multiplying `heuristicVal` by the number of tiles and suddenly there was an exponential speed-up. Problems that were taking 28 seconds before were taking less than 1 second.

**Edit**: It turns out it is not always producing optimal solutions after all with this change. However, I don't understand why it sped up so much or why it is still finding the correct (although suboptimal) answer despite no longer being admissible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break admissability, A* no longer works correctly. Note that *no longer works correctly* doesn't mean you're never gonna get an optimal result - you're just no longer guaranteed to get one. You can also end up converging faster on solution, but what's the point if that solution is not the right one?

Comment: When you say no longer works correctly, do you mean can potentially never find a solution or might produce suboptimal solutions? The end goal of this test is to move visual elements around without them crashing into each other, if it is just suboptimal solutions that are the problem then that may be ok for me if the tradeoff is speed.

Comment: @asimes I don't mean suboptimal solutions. I mean anything. Your heuristic is not admissable (i.e. not a heuristic) you can end up finding anything. A* should always find a solution, however what you're doing really isn't A* if your heuristic isn't a heuristic.

Comment: You mean the multiplied heuristic is not admissible right? I know that one is not, but I am fairly certain the original one would produce optimal solutions (although very slowly sometimes).

Comment: Yes, the multiplied one. Your original one looks ok to me, though I didn't bother to prove it. I assume you did that already.